# Как показать успешную загрузку файла?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть несколько input c типом файл. Как сделать чтобы после загрузки файла появлялось окно о успешной загрузке файла?

Comment: получать ответ от сервера, что файл успешно загружен и через аякс выводить окно, чтобы страница не перезагружалась

Comment: файл не передается на сервер, это просто обычный инпут, нужно просто показать, что файл есть в инпуте.

Comment: Те ты хочешь что бы после того как файл выбран, скрипт бы его показывал? не загружая на сервер.
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-reading-files вот тут очень хорошо разобран данный вопрос

Comment: Предлагаю произвести коррекцию вопроса, так как сам вопрос и комментарий автора не одно и тоже.

Answer (score 3):

И снова AJAX:

```
var fileData = $("#file-input").prop("files")[0];   
var formData = new FormData();                  
formData.append("file", fileData);

$.ajax({
    url: 'load',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
            alert("Данные успешно загружены");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Произошел сбой бла бла бла");
    }
});
```

Comment: Плохой код, и причем тут error? при error файл может не загрузиться?

Comment: @Дмитрий Приходченко, это ивенты. Если успех то показывает сообщение `success`, ошибка - `error`.

Comment: @ДмитрийПриходченко error будет, например, если адрес указанный в url будет недоступен или вернет например 500 ошибку

Comment: @Levelleor и что? 1. Вопрос в другом 2. Я смогу залить файл и отдать error. 3. Вы уверены что этот код зальет файл?

Comment: @Дмитрий Приходченко ты не можешь выбирать когда делать ошибку. Она срабатывает когда сервер отвечает кодом ошибки автоматически. Например 404, зато когда успех возвращает 200.

Comment: @ДмитрийПриходченко либо success, либо error, как раз все хорошо. Может вам не нравится моя обработка этих событий? =) Как раз если файл не загрузится по какой-либо причине. то сработает error.

Comment: @Levelleor Почему я не могу выбирать когда мне делать ошибку?

Comment: @ВалерийГорбунов Ты пробовал свой код? Ты заливал с его помощью файлы + данные? можно пример если есть.

Comment: @ДмитрийПриходченко http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ (Особенно A function to be called if the request fails.). Да и дело не в эроре блин. Суть вопроса не в этом)

Comment: @ДмитрийПриходченко 1000 раз так делал

Comment: @ДмитрийПриходченко чем пример в ответе не нравится?

Comment: @Валерий Горбунов 1. Это простой ajax запрос, суть вопроса не в ajax, он никак не пригодиться при решении данной задачи. 2. Не увидел как ты файл цепляешь в ajax, так что думаю автор не сможет его использовать для загрузки файла например, что если бы, вопрос был про ajax, никак бы не отвечало на него.

Comment: @ВалерийГорбунов не пробовал файлы отправлять в json, поэтому код показался еще и странным

Comment: Думаю, автору стоит добавить тег php (или на чем у него там backend) в вопрос. А то у неподготовленных может сложиться впечатление, что заливку файлов можно осуществить только на клиенте)